# I can't login with a Google account

Tags: macos, system-settings, accounts, google

The problem started after I restored from timemachine, but in a couple of days I saw that my gmail didn't work in Mail.app (my iCloud mail works fine) then I tried log out and log in again (with my google account in system pref.) but after I have selected the services I want to use and press "OK" it will just hang at this screen:

[image]

I hope some of you can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: can you provide more data on this? Do you have two step authorization enabled in Google account? It works like a charm in my case, no problems occurred.

Comment: @Farside I don't have two factor autentification activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, used this command in terminal `chmod -RN ~/Library/`